# Core Data migration with Magical Record fails with "Removed incompatible model version"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I’m trying to add a new version of my core data model. I’ve done this successfully in the past, but this time I simply cannot get it to migrate. I’m using Magical Record for Core Data handling and the scenario is as follows;

1. Core Data stack is setup during `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the AppDelegate
2. Setup method is:

   ```
   [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"MyDb.sqlite"];**
   ```
3. I have added a new version of the .xcdatamodel and set the new version as the current version.
4. When application launches, Magical Record reports the following issue; "Removed incompatible model version".

I thought it had to be an issue with Lightweight Migration rules, but even if I simply add a new version of the .xcdatamodel without making any changes to it, it still won’t migrate. Do you have any ideas about what´s happening? Been struggling with this now for a couple of days and can’t seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using (sorry Swift code), but I am using the latest version of MagicalRecord:

```
    var dbPath = NSPersistentStore.MR_defaultLocalStoreUrl();
    MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Error);
    MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL(dbPath);
```

This piece of code does simple migrations without problems. Just to be sure I added some extra fields and looked at the contents of my database. It's all good.

My MagicalRecord Podfile entry:

`pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => "https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried to setup the stack with an NSUrl instead of passing the name as NSString, but the migration still fails.